# String Conversion

Tags: python, string

s='This is sample'

i need to convert like this

```
s='"This is sample"'
```

output=`"This is sample"`

how to do this in dynamic
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5):

```
orig = 'This is sample'
converted = '"%s"' % orig
```

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> s= 'This is a sample'
>>> s = '"' + s + '"'  # or s = '"%s"' % s
>>> s
'"This is a sample"'
>>> print(s)
"This is a sample"
>>>
```